# Reducing command-line shortcomings caused by excessive number of FFmpeg inputs

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg

I have for a long time used a script that does concatenation for different codecs using complex filters as described [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#differentcodec).

This wiki gives the following example command:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.webm -i input3.mov \
-filter_complex "[0:v:0][0:a:0][1:v:0][1:a:0][2:v:0][2:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[outv][outa]" \
-map "[outv]" -map "[outa]" output.mkv
```

My problem is that if you have many small clips that need combining in this manner, this scales disastrously.

While for this example it appears as if the complex filter is the troublemaker, the pressure for this can actually be lessened to a constant burden through the use of `-filter_complex_script` which puts the entire filter string in an external file, which scales perfectly.

Thus, the only problem that remains are the input files. I wouldn't hit this limit nearly as easily if I was not constrained by the different paths and lengthy auto-generated filenames, but those are out of my control to change. Unfortunately, my situation has grown to where the 8,000 odd characters Windows offers me is not enough.

So what I am looking for is (roughly) something like an input file script. I have seen mentions of the *concat demuxer* that has something along those lines, but I can't quite figure out how that would work. For as far I can tell, it would throw everything into a single file input and make it impossible to execute the complex filter script concatenation. Not to mention: the wiki link above mentions clearly it needs to be the same codec, timebase, etc for all files, which does not apply to my situation.

How do I get rid of my command-line-length worries and forever-more forget about the thing known as command-line character limitations?

Comment: If you can't use the concat demuxer, I suggest you run a batch script to create abbreviated soft links in one directory for all files in desired input order. and then supply those names as inputs to ffmpeg.

Comment: If you problem is with command line limitations it might be worth looking into solving it programmatically. Simple scripting languages such as Python have bindings for ffmpeg: https://pypi.org/project/ffmpeg-python/#files

Comment: Can't you use movie/amovie source filter in -filter_complex_script?

Comment: @PaulB.Mahol That is what I eventually ended up discovering a day later. (I hadn't seen your comment before now, I'm afraid.) If you'll put it into a proper answer (with a mention regarding the escaping of filenames), I'll flag it as answered. :-)

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to shift the limitation. It could work to a certain degree.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19355351) says:

> POSIX denotes this limit `ARG_MAX` and on POSIX conformant systems you can query it with
>
> ```
> $ getconf ARG_MAX    # Get argument limit in bytes
> ```
>
> E.g. on Cygwin this is 32000, and on the different BSDs and Linux systems I use it is anywhere from 131072 to 2621440.

The value in Cygwin is relatively low (I suspect some Windows limitation may be the cause), but it's still four times higher than 8000 you mentioned. I don't know the value of `ARG_MAX` in Windows Subsystem for Linux.

A step further would be to run `ffmpeg` on (possibly virtual) Linux.